# Sending an email message with highpriority using Exchange API for java

Tags: java, exchange-server

I wan to set my email priority. I am using API for exchange server.
I suppose with this method "msg.setImportance(value);" i can resolve my prob. but I did not handle the syntax.
Please, someone if can explain to me how I do that

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
                ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("dan.oncioiu@alcatel-lucent.com", "Blatjardon1990");
                service.setCredentials(credentials);
                service.setUrl(new java.net.URI("https://" + "EMEAXCH.zeu.alcatel-lucent.com"
                    + "/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
                service.setTraceEnabled(true);

                EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(service);

                msg.setImportance(value);

                msg.setSubject("Hello world!");
                msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Mesaj trimis din JAVA"));
                msg.getToRecipients().add("Leontin.Talpai@alcatel-lucent.com");
                msg.send();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceLocalException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found how to setup that with this.

```
msg.setImportance(Importance.High);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Importance field is an enum, which you can find here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/Importance.java

Comment: I tried to write "msg.setImportance("HIGH");" but none of the inside value in enum it is not functioning